# batch rename the files in a folder

Tags: command-line, batch-file, batch-rename

I have some files (about 10000 files) in bellow format

```
SDEF-2001-23965-236.pdf
SlkF-1991-65-123.pdf
```

I want to check if the file name is in wanted format rename it by removing 4 characters from end

```
SDEF-2001-23965-236.pdf >>SDEF-2001-23965.pdf

SlkF-1991-65-123.pdf    >>SlkF-1991-65.pdf
```

I do not know how should I create a .bat file that can do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You need "String Manipulation" in DOS, the following link is useful:

http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

---

If you have `*.pdf` files with format `aaaa-bbb-cc-ddd.ext` (4 parts + extension)

Create a file named `rn.bat`:

```
@echo off
set str=%1
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=- " %%a in ("%str%") do set p1=%%a&set p2=%%b&set p3=%%c&set p4=%%d
set ext=%str:~-4%
set "result=%p1%-%p2%-%p3%%ext%"
ren %1 %result%
```

Create a file named `rnall.bat`:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (%1) do rml.bat %%i
```

Then, enter command: `rnall *.pdf` in commmand line.

*This is not best code, you can use functions to do it better*

Comment: I wrote sth. like this

    @echo off 
    SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion 
    
    FOR %%A IN (*.pdf) DO (
     set st2="%%A"
     set st1=%st2:~0,-8%
     echo REN %%A %st1%
    )
    GOTO :eof
    
    pause

but set st2="%%A" does not work
I found it by echo the command

Comment: @ghasedak: You are enabling delayed expansion in this example, but you are not using it, why? I mean, `%st2:~0,-8%` should probably be `!st2:~0,-8!` and `%st1%` should be `!st1!`.